# Calcular total carrinho em php

Tags: php, web-service, matemática

Estou com uma dúvida fiz um carrinho de compras e o cálculo do frete usando o `webservice` do correios.Agora preciso que o frete some ao valor total mais não estou conseguindo.Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Código carrinho:

```
foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $quantidade)
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = '$id'";
                $query = mysql_query($sql);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
                {
                    $produto = $row['nome'];
                    $preco = $row['preco'];
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $altura = $row['altura'];
                    $largura = $row['largura'];
                    $comprimento = $row['comprimento'];
                    $peso = $row['peso'];
                    $cepOrigem = $row['cepOrigem'];

                    $sub = $preco * $quantidade;
                    $total = $total + $sub;

                    $alturaTotal = $alturaTotal + $altura;
                    $pesoTotal = $pesoTotal + $peso;

                    if($maiorLargura < $largura = $row['largura'])
                    $maiorLargura = $largura = $row['largura'];

                    if($maiorComprimento < $comprimento = $row['comprimento'])
                    $maiorComprimento = $comprimento = $row['comprimento'];
```

Código correios:

```
require_once("carrinho.php");

// post variaveis
    $data['sCepDestino'] = $_POST['sCepDestino'];
    $data['nCdServico'] = $_POST['nCdServico'];

// variaveis de tamanho
    $data['nVlAltura'] = $_POST['nVlAltura'];
    $data['nVlLargura'] = $_POST['nVlLargura'];
    $data['nVlComprimento'] = $_POST['nVlComprimento'];
    $data['nVlPeso'] = $_POST['nVlPeso'];

// variaveis obrigatórias
    $data['sCepOrigem'] = $_GET['sCepOrigem'] = $cepOrigem;
    $data['nCdEmpresa'] = '';
    $data['sDsSenha'] = '';
    $data['nCdformato'] = '1';
    $data['nVlDiametro'] = '0';
    $data['sCdMaoPropria'] = 'n';
    $data['nVlValorDeclarado'] = '0';
    $data['sCdAvisoRecebimento'] = 'n';
    $data['StrRetorno'] = 'xml';

// código do correio para enviar e receber dados  
    $data = http_build_query($data);

    $url = 'http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx';
    $curl = curl_init($url . '?' . $data);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $result = simplexml_load_string($result);

    foreach($result -> cServico as $row)
    {
        if($row -> Erro == 0)
        {
            $frete = $row -> Valor;
            $entrega = $row -> PrazoEntrega;
            echo "<table id='FreteTable'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>Frete</td>";
                    echo "<td>$frete</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>Prazo de entrega</td>";
                    echo "<td>$entrega</td>";
                echo "</tr>";   
            echo "</table>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $row -> MsgErro;   
        }
    } 
       ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para usar **Api dos Correios**, a melhor forma é montar uma função que traga somente as informações dos `arrays`, sem `html` envolvido.

Após isso, faça o laço para listar em `checkbox` o `array` gerado pela consulta.

Assim que o usuário selecionar que tipo de frete vai querer, `SEDEX`, `PAC` etc, **guarde o código** do serviço em uma `variável de sessão`, `cookie` ou `banco de dados`, e para calcular, faça a consulta novamente enviando o cep, kg, dimensões etc, o array sempre vai ser o mesmo. A diferença para saber qual frete foi selecionado, use o código do serviço como filtro, e para efetuar este filtro, use a função [in_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php) para manter o frete selecionado, depois é somar, pois da forma como você está fazendo, não há possibilidade de controle destas informações.

Espero ter ajudado! ;)

Comment: Só como vou fazer a consulta novamente?

Comment: @LeonardoSilva Envie o CEP e as dimensões novamente, a cada atualização no carrinho, seu filtro para o tipo de frete escolhido é o código do serviço, mas o array é o mesmo.